# Laravel change timezone for users according to preference

Tags: laravel, datetime, timezone

I have a multi-timezone based project. The project has a lot of DateTime fields. All users can set their own timezone from their profile preferences.

Converting these dates from UTC to the users' timezone is cumbersome. I am doing this each time when I manipulate the date/time.

How to handle this? I don't want to call the DateTime conversion function on millions of location? What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Please don't downvote, close. It's a humble request

Comment: Please prefer this url your answer is here (i.e https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/user-specified-timezones-config)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem before. I solved this way:

1) Get the timezone when user register using [geoip_time_zone_by_country_and_region](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-time-zone-by-country-and-region.php)
 function using the Country Code which is a world wide common code.

2) I stored the timezone in the users table.

3) I created a global middleware that reads if a users is logged in and set the timezone using [date_default_timezone_set](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) function provides by PHP.

That's how its working.

**Pros**

You just have to do it once and will work forever.

**Cons**

You need the list of countries and country code set correctly or it will fail